# Set readOnly attribute for different page in React JS

Tags: reactjs, readonly-attribute

I had 2 different files and combined it int one web page. At one.js file in contain the text input and at the second.js files I had confirm button. What I want is, the user filled the value in one.js files than click confirm button on second page, the text input will be read only.

one.js

```
<TextField
    type="text" 
    name={'jobs'}
    value=''
    fullWidth
/>
```

second.js

```
<Button
  variant="contained"
  disabled={!this.state.valid  || this.state.isDisabled }

  >
  Confirm
  </Button>
```

So far, I knew how to do it if using a single .js file. So is it possible to do this if have 2 different files?

Thanks for the clue

Comment: You could use a state in the container (parent) component to control the disabled state of the input by passing it as a prop to `<TextField>` and a function that sets this state as a prop to `<Button>`.

Comment: Thanks @tromgy, any example simple link to implement this. Sorry

Comment: You can look at this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-sanne-evp66y?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Bekka has your question been answered? If not, provide more information so that an adequate answer can be given. Please accept the given answer if your question has been met with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is essentially a shared `state` between components, which updates as soon as the `Button` component is pressed and defines the read-only property of the `TextField` component. You need to use the respective `state` approaches for class and functional components, since state changes need to trigger a rerender.

The state should be defined in an encapsulating parent component. A possible implementation, using functional components and hooks, can be found below:

Parent.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {TextFieldComponent} from 'one.js';
import {ConfirmButton} from 'two.js';
    
const Parent = () => {
  const [content, setContent] = React.useState("");
  const [isReadOnly, setIsReadOnly] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <TextFieldComponent 
        readOnly={isReadOnly}
        content={content}
        setContent={setContent}
      />
    
      <ConfirmButton 
        setIsReadOnly={setIsReadOnly}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

one.js (example without imports)

```
export const TextFieldComponent = ({content, setContent,isReadOnly}) => {
  return(
     <TextField
       type="text" 
       name={'jobs'}
       value={content}
       fullWidth
       readOnly={isReadOnly}
       onInput={text => setContent(text)}
     />
  )
}
```

two.js (example without imports)

```
export const ConfirmButton = ({setReadOnly}) => {
  return(
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      disabled={!this.state.valid  || this.state.isDisabled }
      onClick={() => setReadOnly(true)}
    >
      Confirm
    </Button>
  )
}
```

I would highly recommend reading the official documentation regarding [state and lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).